# Simple Noetherian domain which is not a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

> I need a simple Noetherian domain which is not a division ring.

I do know that this ring must not be Artinian, since otherwise it would be a division ring. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Weyl algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) is a Noetherian domain which is a non-commutative ring, and is not a division ring.

Comment: And it is also a simple ring. I think this is the only example I know of a simple domain... it would be neat if more showed up here.

Comment: There are lots of such examples. For starters, there are the q-analogs of the Weyl algebra studied by Hayashi (and two-parameter analogs studied by others). See also V.V. Bavula's generalized Weyl algebras and D.A. Jordan's ambiskew polynomial rings. Both of these classes (which are related) have many simple noetherian examples which are not division rings.